# The ubuntu software center disappeared when I changed the GUI

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, software-center, gui

My Ubuntu used to freeze all the time, then I decided to change the Unity/Gnome GUI to the Lubuntu environment. The I typed the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Then after an upgrade I restarted the pc, but after I chose the Lubuntu desktop environment in the initialization, my Ubuntu Software Center disappeared, why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu does not use the Ubuntu Software Center, but it uses Muon Package Manager instead.

Your desktop environment (DE) is not a singular package, but an entire suite of packages with many moving parts that all work together to make up your DE.

It is often a very messy process to try to swap desktop environments on an installed system.

This is the reason that Ubuntu is released in several different flavors.  The best path is to simply install the version of Ubuntu that has the desktop environment that you want.  In the case of the LXQt desktop environment, the installation candidate is [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/).

Each flavor of Ubuntu also allows you to "Try Ubuntu" so that you can test drive the operating system and it's DE before you take on the hefty task of adopting a new DE.